# Is there any benefit - besides cosmetics - to purchase a new lobby or roof?

Tags: tiny-tower-vegas

I found that you can purchase a different roof and different lobby at the cost of TowerBux.   Is there any benefit to changing these? (% increase in demand of X, % increase of Bitzens, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

No. The roof and the lobby being changed is solely for cosmetic purposes. According to [Touch Arcade](http://toucharcade.com/2014/09/03/tiny-tower-vegas-guide-tips/), there really isn't a boost of some sort for your tower. It's only for cosmetics.